# What to use to create search engine using onKeyReleased event

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, javafx, keyrelease

I am trying to create a search bar which will search the entered string or character from db. While first character is typed in textfield it should wait for next 200ms, if next character is entered within that time then it will restart the counter and again wait for next 200ms if not, then it will search from db.

Here is some code which i tried but not work for me

```
@FXML protected void keyReleased(KeyEvent evt)throws Exception {
   if (evt.getCode() != KeyCode.BACK_SPACE) {
       String ch = evt.getText();
       String[] myArray = new String[5];
       run();
       searchFrmDb(ch, myArray);
   }
}
public void run(){
   for(int i=1;i<5;i++){
      try{
          Thread.sleep(200);
      }catch(InterruptedException e){System.out.println(e);}
     System.out.println(i);

    } 
}
public void searchFrmDb(String ch,String[] myArray){
     //db search operation ...
}
```

I am new in java help me out to sort out my problem
What should i use `thread` or `Timer` or anything else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using a [`PauseTransition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/PauseTransition.html) for functionality like this.

```
public class ControllerClass {

    private final PauseTransition pauseBeforeSearch = new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(200));

    @FXML protected void keyReleased(KeyEvent evt)throws Exception {
       if (evt.getCode() != KeyCode.BACK_SPACE) {
           pauseBeforeSearch.setOnFinished(e -> {
               searchFrmDb(evt.getText(), new String[5]);
           });
           pauseBeforeSearch.playFromStart();
       }
    }

}
```

Comment: The exact answer which i want but I need to pass argument to `searchFrmDb ()`

Comment: What's stopping you from passing an argument to the method?

Comment: in `keyReleased ` event i have an array that i want to pass ... how can i ?

Comment: Update your question to show what you mean. In the question you don't pass anything to that method.

Comment: Thank you very much ... You are the saviour

Answer (score 0):

I would have a look at `java.util.Timer` and `java.util.TimerTask`:

```
class SearchTimerTask extends TimerTask{
    @Override
    public void run(){
        searchFrmDb();
    }

    @Override
    public void cancel(){
        super.cancel();
        //handle cancellation logic if necessary
    }
}
```

Keep a reference to a `Timer` and a `TimerTask` somewhere:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask task;
```

Then in your key event handler you simply cancel the current task if there is one and fire up a new one:

```
@FXML protected void keyReleased(KeyEvent evt)throws Exception {
   if (evt.getCode() != KeyCode.BACK_SPACE) {
        if(task != null){
            task.cancel();
            task = new SearchTimerTask();
        }
        timer.schedule(task, 200);
   }
}
```

Comment: is it necessary to create a class `SearchTimerTask `? Because i have controller class in which i am writing this code

Comment: well, you need an implementation of the `TimerTask` class to be able to schedule it on a `Timer`. You can add this class as an (anonymous) inner class to your controller class if you want to keep the logic inside the controller.